# Magento 2 - How can I change the quantity of a product (on product page) with php or js?

Tags: javascript, php, magento, e-commerce, magento2

I am looking for a way to change the value of the quantity box from the code in stead of manually changing it on the product page.

`$Uitkomst` has to be in the input once the form is submitted.

I haven't been able to find the answer to my problem so any help at all would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

the value which I need in the qty input comes from this form:

```html
<form action="?" method="POST">
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <input name="breedte" type="text" maxlength="40" placeholder="Breedte (in millimeters)" required>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <input name="lengte" type="text" maxlength="40"  placeholder="Lengte (in millimeters)" required>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Toevoegen aan winkelwagen">
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</form>
<?php
   if (isset($_POST["lengte"]))
   {
       $Lengte = $_POST["lengte"];
       $Breedte = $_POST["breedte"];
       $Uitkomst = $Lengte * $Breedte;
       echo $Uitkomst;
       
   }
   ?>     
<div class="control">
   <input
      name="qty"
      id="qty"
      value="<?= block->getProductDefaultQty() * 
         1 ?>"
      title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Qty')) ?>"
      class="input-text qty"
      />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem,

in a CustomForm.phtml file I put

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View */
?>
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<div>
    <div class="CalculatorForm">
        <form onsubmit="event.preventDefault();fillQty();" id="form_id">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input name="breedte" type="number" maxlength="40" placeholder="Breedte (in millimeters)" required>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input name="lengte" type="number" maxlength="40"  placeholder="Lengte (in millimeters)" required>
                    </td>  
                </tr>  
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" value="Bereken prijs">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        <div class="field qty">
            <!--<?php #if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity()) :?>-->
            <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="number"
                    name="qty"
                    id="qty"
                    min="0"
                    value="<?= $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                    title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Qty')) ?>"
                    class="input-text qty"
                    data-validate="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                />
            </div>
            <?php #endif; ?>
            <script>
                function fillQty(){
                    $('#qty').val($('input[name="breedte"]').val() * $('input[name="lengte"]').val());
                    return false;};
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and in the original addtocart.phtml I put

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View */
?>
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct();?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = __('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()) :?>
<div class="box-tocart">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <div class="control">
            <?php if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity()) :?>
                <input type="number"
                    name="qty"
                    id="qty"
                    min="0"
                    value="<?= $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                    title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Qty')) ?>"
                    class="input-text qty"
                    data-validate="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                />
            <?php endif ?>
        </div>
        <div class="actions">
            <button 
                type="submit"
                title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($buttonTitle) ?>"
                class="action primary tocart"
                id="product-addtocart-button">
                <span>
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml($buttonTitle) ?>
                </span>
            </button>
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "#product_addtocart_form": {
                "Magento_Catalog/js/validate-product": {}
        }
        </script> 
    </div>
</div>
```

I also put `<script src="{{MEDIA_URL}}jQuery-3.3.1.js?v=1.x"></script>` in the html head in the magento backend.

this solved my problem. thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the answer also abit.

It does not refresh the page, is that what you need?

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <form onsubmit="event.preventDefault();fillQty();" id="form_id">
       <table>
          <tr>
             <td>
                <input name="breedte" type="text" maxlength="40" placeholder="Breedte (in millimeters)" required>
             </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>
                <input name="lengte" type="text" maxlength="40"  placeholder="Lengte (in millimeters)" required>
             </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Toevoegen aan winkelwagen">
             </td>
          </tr>
       </table>
    </form>    
    <div class="control">
       <input
          type="text"
          name="qty"
          id="qty"
          value="<?= block->getProductDefaultQty() * 
             1 ?>"
          title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Qty')) ?>"
          class="input-text qty"
          />
    </div>
    <script>
      function fillQty() {
        $('#qty').val($('input[name="breedte"]').val() * $('input[name="lengte"]').val());
        return false;
      };
    </script>
```

Comment: The .js you commented did not really seem to do anything.
The same problem still occurs, I get a blanc page when i try to open it.

Thank you for helping though.

Comment: The js you commented refreshes the page when the form is submitted, although i fied the "white screen" problem.

Comment: To be honest i didnt really get the question ... sry, can you explain some more maybe i can help better.

Comment: Yes of course, Heres my problem: I need a form on my product page, this form is there so that the customer can enter how long (lengte) and wide (breedte) their product is going to be when they order is. since the price of my product is per unit I need the form to multiply the 2 entered numbers (therefore Lengte * breedte) and the answer needs to go into the qty field so that the price of the product is dependant on de entered values.

if you need any further explaination feel free to ask.

Milan Jacobs.